# How to deserialize an object field in Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am not able to deserialize an object field using Jersey with a JSON data representation. The field "data" can contain an Integer, String, List of String, ... or any other JAXB tagged object.

This is my code:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ReturnValue{    

    private Object data;

    public ReturnValue() { }

    public ReturnValue(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ReturnValue [data=" + data + "]";
    }

}
```

The Client looks as follows:

```
public class MyClient {

    private String location = "http://localhost:9998/test";
    private Client client;
    private WebResource resource;

    public MyClient() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
        client = Client.create(clientConfig);
        resource = client.resource(location);
    }

    private void test() {
        ClientResponse response = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
        ReturnValue value = response.getEntity(ReturnValue.class);
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClient client = new MyClient();
        client.test();
    }

}
```

That is the resource:

```
@Singleton
@Path("/test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object get() {
        return Response.ok(new ReturnValue("TEST_SERVER")).build();
    }

}
```

The serialzed Object looks right:

```
{"data":{"@type":"xs:string","$":"TEST_SERVER"}}
```

This is the output on the console:

```
ReturnValue [data={@type=xs:string, $=TEST_SERVER}]
```

As you can see, the String is not instantiated. What can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you use `java.lang.Object` as type of `data` in `ReturnValue`. Because of this, JAXB will marshall the result along with the type of your data (which is actually `String`) so it will know how to unmarshall your object on client side.

The following code using you initial `ReturnValue`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JAXB.marshal(new ReturnValue("cvb"), baos);
System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
```

will produce this output (see xsi:type="xs:string"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<returnValue>
    <data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">cvb</data>
</returnValue>
```

, but if you change the type of data attribute to String it will look like due to the way Jaxb handles Strings and primitives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<returnValue>
    <data>cvb</data>
</returnValue>
```

Similar, you test will output:

```
TEST_SERVER
```